# Configuring separate ssh and https urls in Gitlens

Tags: gitlens

I have a repository that I connect to via SSH on one subdomain but the http website is on a separate subdomain. When I copy the URL of a page using Gitlens I get the wrong URL as it is using the SSH subdomain and not the web subdomain. I see that I can use `"gitlens.remotes"` to configure this but I can't get it to identify my repository and I don't understand whether I need to define all of the `"urls"` or if there is a shorter way since it is a gitlab site.

How do I configure `gitlens.remotes` to point to one address as the website and one for ssh?